# types 'X' and 'string' have no overlap.ts(2367)

Tags: javascript, typescript, material-ui

I have this type,

```
export type AutocompleteChangeReason =
 | 'createOption'
 | 'selectOption'
 | 'removeOption'
 | 'clear'
 | 'blur';
```

the bellow compression gives me an error.

```
(reason:AutocompleteChangeReason)=>{
   const s: AutocompleteChangeReason = 'selectOption';
   if (reason === s) {

   }
}
```

I know I can convert them to a string by using String.

```
String(a)===String(b)
```

what is the best practice to this case?

The error:
This comparison appears to be unintentional because the types 'ControlledOptionsType' and 'string' have no overlap.ts(2367)

Comment: What is `reason`? Is it a string? If yes, why? It should be a `AutocompleteChangeReason`.

Comment: Could you provide a [mcve]? I don't get the error you do: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCCBXGEDGEC2YANsDMAMIAWAhgHYDmwASsNQM4S1wC8AsAFBwAPnADkOKKzIB5MDACWnUQOFi2wEjhiyFSlSNGT8EAG7Adi2ssEGcJalGurRAIyIZHAbhUCAJsDsHVDxaNnhJdk4ALjgwqHkGb34BELDYmMxsPEISMio6RhZIrm41DQDtOUtRJPkAMzgACgiOEu5StgBKOABvAQEAXwEgA) What is `ControlledOptionsType`? The error mention it yet it's nowhere to be seen in your code example.

Comment: After edit: still can't reproduce it: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCCBXGEDGEC2YANsDMAMIAWAhgHYDmwASsNQM4S1wC8AsAFBwAPnADkOKKzIB5MDACWnUQOFi2wEjhiyFSlSNGT8EAG7Adi2ssEGcJalGurRAIyIZHAbgE-+ACkl2TgAuTGw8QhIyKjpGFiDaAEpuAD4AbxU4ODxaNng2YPQsXAJiUgoaBmZWDi5uNQ1gLQslb0Es+QAzOACazh5uerZEuAz+TLgAXwFp-iA)

Comment: I don't know what change, but for now it works.
Thank you for your help!

this is the source code
https://codesandbox.io/s/muddy-sun-sxh1nh?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 2):

I would use an enum instead of a type

```
export enum AutocompleteChangeReason {
 createOption = 'createOption'
 selectOption = 'selectOption'
}
```

etc..

Then when comparing a string such as

```
const something = AutocompleteChangeReason.createOption // this would be typed correctly
```

and let you compare such as:

```
if(something === AutocompleteChangeReason.selectOption)
```

edit:
if you want to force as string that you know that is of a certain type
use casting such as

```
const whatever ='createOption' as AutocompleteChangeReason
```

Comment: Its Mui type, not mine.
so I have to force it;
I would have liked to used enum here.

Comment: if (reason as AutocompleteChangeReason  === s) 

this should work i believe

Comment: reason is AutocompleteChangeReason

Comment: @user19479975 Seems like your typescript is having issues identifying that one of the values is of type AutocompleteChangeReason

i would just write

`(reason as AutocompleteChangeReason === s as AutocompleteChangeReason)`

Answer (score -2):

As you are using the `===` ( strict equality ) operator, the types will also be considered here, The `controlledOptionsType` might have some other properties, which are not in the `AutocompleteChangeReason` hence the error but doing `reason.toString` will do the job.

Comment: depends on what is reason

Comment: this is the same type.

Comment: as per the question, the error message has a mention of `ControlledOptionsType` which is the type of `reason` and these two types are different.

Comment: `===` only considers the JS type. So, comparing two strings wouldn't be `false` just because they belong to two different TS union types.  [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UBEAzA9mpUA+yBGAhgE5ICwAUKJFAEIL7Fa5KEBeZ5FAxmgHYDOwKAQBcsei0YBubn0FQ8YuokkkZncgEsUUABQEE8RHgCUUAN4Uo1qDwFoANhAB0DtAHNdSCAEcArgQOSCbqAL4UQA)

Comment: And `===` wouldn't cause a TypeScript error message `This comparison appears to be unintentional because the types 'ControlledOptionsType' and 'string' have no overlap.ts(2367)`

Comment: @jabaa depends. [It might if two unions of strings don't overlap](https://tsplay.dev/WYL13m) but that's not what OP showed. Well, OP didn't really conclusively show anything. The error message doesn't mention the union they have but some other type. [For example, the real reason might be similar to this](https://tsplay.dev/NnljeW). In other words the code in the question doesn't match the error reported.

Comment: @VLAZ Yes, I was unclear. The comparison could cause the TypeScript message, but irrelevant whether it's strict equality (`===`) or equality (`==`).